# Custom exception class not working in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

What I am trying to do is find the todo with the id and when it is not present it throws a custom exception. However on postman I cannot see the exception on postman. It doesn't show anything.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

ExceptionResponse.class

```
package com.lcwd.todo.exceptions;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

public class ExceptionResponse {
    private String message;
    private boolean success;
    private HttpStatus status;

    public ExceptionResponse(String message, boolean success, HttpStatus status) {
        this.message = message;
        this.success = success;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public ExceptionResponse() {
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public HttpStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(HttpStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

GlobalExceptionHandler.class

```
package com.lcwd.todo.exceptions;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);
    @ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> nullPointerException(NullPointerException ex){
        System.out.println("This is null pointer exception");
        logger.info("It is nullPointerException from GlobalExceptionHandler");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> resourceNotFoundExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException ex){
        ExceptionResponse response=new ExceptionResponse();
        response.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        response.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        response.setSuccess(false);
        return  ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(response);
    }
}
```

ResourceNotFoundException.java

```
package com.lcwd.todo.exceptions;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{
    private String message;
    private HttpStatus status;

    public ResourceNotFoundException( String message, HttpStatus status) {
        super(message);
        this.message = message;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public ResourceNotFoundException(){

    }



    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public HttpStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(HttpStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

getToDofunction

```
 public ToDo getSingleToDo(int id){
        ToDo todo=new ToDo();
        for(ToDo todo1:todos){
            if (todo1.getId() == id) {
                return todo1;
            }
            todo=todo1;
        }
        if(todo==null){
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Resource not found exception",HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: As you are initialize todo with a new instance, the exception will never be thrown.  Use a debugger to verify it.

Comment: Make sure that your Spring Boot application is running correctly and that the endpoint is accessible. Check if you can access other endpoints successfully.

Verify that the GlobalExceptionHandler class is being scanned and registered by your Spring Boot application. You can check the console logs to see if there are any errors related to scanning or registering the ControllerAdvice class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `todos` is not null but doesn't contain the id you want (including if `todos` is empty): In your loop, you are setting `todo` equal to every single object you look at no matter if the ids match, so when it finishes unless it found a matching id and returned early it will always be set either to the last item in the list or to the initial `todo=new ToDo()`. So it will never be null. But actually, do you really need this object? What if you remove it and just always throw the exception if the loop is finished? Cause if the loop is finished, the resource hasn't been found. This also begs the question, what is the semantic difference here between returning null and throwing ResourceNotFoundException? What does returning null actually mean? I suspect you may not need to return null if the exception indicates not found.